# How can i call a date function at odbc?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2005, odbc

I need to get from an ODBC database a name, last name of employee filtered by:
The division and the current date = birthdate.
I am using this query :

```
SELECT 
`Sheet1$`.name + ' ' +  `Sheet1$`.lastname as [fullname]   
FROM `C:\Users\Angalia\Desktop\ormatbirthdays`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`  
    where `Sheet1$`.division = 'metal' ;
```

How do I add the date filtering?

I tried working with the ms date function

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2005? You know that's completely unsupported now, right?

Comment: I have a legacy system that works with SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I need the odbc to read from an excel using the query filters that i wrote at the first question.

Comment: If you're reading from Excel you would normally be use the ACE or JET drivers. If you're using ACE, then you can add a `WHERE` clause like like in "normal" SQL. You already have a one `WHERE` clause there so why not simply add an `AND` and the additional clause you need? not really sure what we're missing here.

Comment: "the current date = birthdate": It is a difference whether current date (01/28/2019) is the exact birthdate of someone or whether someone celebrates his birthday today. If the latter, then the month of the birthdate is equal the month of todays date  AND the day of the birthdate is equal the day of todays date, independent of the year.

Comment: I need the query to this action: SELECT name+last name AS Fullname FROM table where division = metal AND Curentdate/DayOfMonth = OR contains birthdate DayOfMonth any suggestion of hows to write this quewry?